# RuntimeError (in Raspberry Pi) produced at a defined variable

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I have got the following RuntimeError in Python 2.7 with Raspberry Pi:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ldrmqtt.py", line 96, in <module>
 main()
File "ldrmqtt.py", line 72, in main
 ldrData= rc_time(pin_to_circuit)
File "ldrmqtt.py", line 53, in rc_time
 GPIO.setup(pin_to_circuit, GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: Please set pin numbering mode using GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) or GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
```

I have connected an LDR to my Raspberry Pi and I am trying to send the values to Thingspeak using the MQTT broker. I am using Python 2.7.9

Here is a code snippet:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

pin_to_circuit=7

 def rc_time (pin_to_circuit):
    count=0
    GPIO.setup(pin_to_circuit, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin_to_circuit, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.15)
    GPIO.setup(pin_to_circuit, GPIO.IN)

    while(GPIO.input(pin_to_circuit) == GPIO.LOW):
        count +=1
    return count


try:
    while True:
        print rc_time(pin_to_circuit)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()

def main():
    print 'starting...'
    ldrData= rc_time(pin_to_circuit)
    tPayload= "field1=" % ldrData

    while True:
        try:
            publish.single(topic, payload=tPayload, hostname=mqttHost, 
            port=tPort, tls=tTLS, transport= tTransport)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        except:      
            print: 'Error publishing the data'


 #call main
  if __name__=='__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the numbering mode for GPIO ports:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
```

1. `GPIO.BOARD` – Board numbering scheme. The pin numbers follow the pin numbers on header P1.
2. `GPIO.BCM` – Broadcom chip-specific pin numbers. These pin numbers follow the lower-level numbering system defined by the Raspberry Pi’s Broadcom-chip brain.

Comment: I did set it, it's just that I didn't add that part in the code snippet. Check the code snippet again, I have updated it

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean by setting the inline of that function?

Comment: I think `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)` not executed

Comment: Should I add it in the main? I think the problem is with with 'ldrData' variable

Comment: This: 'ldrData= rc_time(pin_to_circuit)'

Comment: Check the Traceback

Comment: Adding the following lines: 'GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)'

'pin_to_circuit=7' in the main solved the prob. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it seems that you need to set GPIO.setmode.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  

# for GPIO numbering, choose BCM  
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  

# or, for pin numbering, choose BOARD  
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)  

# but you can't have both, so only use one!!!
```

There is a nice write-up to be found here: http://raspi.tv/2013/rpi-gpio-basics-4-setting-up-rpi-gpio-numbering-systems-and-inputs

Comment: I did set it, it's just that I didn't add that part in the code snippet. Check the code snippet again, I have updated it